# "non-numeric argument to binary operator" error with plotly facet_grid

Tags: r, plotly

I'd like to create a facet plot with 4 scatter plots, however my code below is returning the error `"Error in p + facet_grid(party ~ state) : non-numeric argument to binary operator"`. Any ideas why?

```
# plotly minimum reproducible example
library(plotly)

# create dummy data set
state <- c("MA", "MA", "CA", "CA")
party <- c("Republican", "Democrat", "Republican", "Democrat")
age <- c(45,32,28,76)
FICO <- c(675, 789, 425, 690)
df <- data.frame(state, party, age , FICO)

# Create 4 scatter plots
p <- plot_ly(data = df, x = ~age, y = ~FICO)
p <- p + facet_grid(party ~ state)
print(p)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is coming about from trying to `+` a `facet_grid` to a plotly object.  As far as i know this is not a valid operation to perform on a plotly object.  If you create the facet grid plot using only `ggplot2` then you can call `ggplotly` on the plot to apply plotly's interactivity.

```
# plotly minimum reproducible example
library(plotly)

# create dummy data set
state <- c("MA", "MA", "CA", "CA")
party <- c("Republican", "Democrat", "Republican", "Democrat")
age <- c(45,32,28,76)
FICO <- c(675, 789, 425, 690)
df <- data.frame(state, party, age , FICO)

# Create 4 scatter plots
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=age, y=FICO)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(party ~ state)

ggplotly(p)
```